# Not able to insert text into List<string>

Tags: c#, list

I want to add the string to the List at certain position. I tried using List.Insert() method as well as InsertRange(). Both are giving me error.

```
     //Using InsertRange() Method
     string[] msg = { "Hi", "There",
                        "Good", "Morning" };
     List<string> Lines=new List<string>;
     Lines.InsertRange(4, msg);

     //Using Insert() Method
     string[] msg = { "Hi, Good Morning" };
     List<string> Lines=new List<string>;
     Lines.Insert(1, msg);
```

Please suggest solution.

Comment: There are so many basic errors ([here is a compiling and running similar version](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ow6fuY)) that I would suggest you purchase a book about C# programming.

Answer (score 1):

`Insert` method takes a `signle string` not an `array`

```
Lines.Insert(1, msg[0]);
```

And first paramter of  `InsertRange` is index on which to insert. You are inserting the array on `4th` index while `List Lines` doesn't have `4th index.`

Insert array on `0 index`.

```
Lines.InsertRange(0, msg);
```

Comment: This gives me an error

argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.COllections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to fix the syntax errors in the code, that is you have to declare a list of string like this : `List<string> Lines=new List<string>();` in your case you missed the `()`(hope that it is not a typo). Then for Insert as well as InsertRange, the given index should be valid. which means the specified index will be available in the collection.

Consider the first snippet, the `InsertRange`

The collection is Empty in this stage, and you are trying to insert to the index `4` which is invalid at this stage and leads to ArgumentOutOfRangeException. So you can try with

```
 Lines.InsertRange(0, msg);
```

And also try with AddRange instead for InserRange, which also helpful in this case:

```
Lines.AddRange(msg);
```

Now let me consider the second snippet. With the `.Insert` method you are allowed to insert an item to the collection to a valid index. But in your case you are trying to insert a array of strings to an index in a List which is not permitted you have to give a single string instead for array. Remember one thing here also index is an important factor which should be valid. You can try .Add() as well if you don't want want the new element in a particular position. It will be added to the last position.

Comment: Yes, I have defined list as msg = new List<string>(10)

Comment: @BhushanKhajone: You are limiting the size of string to `10` then why not continue with an array? anyway I have updated the answer could you please take a look?